# How to secure a GraphQL API?

Tags: security, ssl, graphql

I'm building an application based on GraphQL and I'm wondering if there're standard way to secure a GraphQL API?

For instance, if the API can provide a list of all accounts, I don't want that someone not granted can access this list.

```
{
   allUsers
   {
      Token
   }
}
```

Is there another way to implement that?

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I found this great article : https://scaphold.io/community/questions/graphql-security-best-practices/ , I'm not using GraphQL currently, but I can keep you informed.